# Convergence of haplo-group

Tags: probability, expectation, biology

Every man inherits his [haplo-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplogroup) from his father, and thus the male lineage can be traced back.

Given a population $n$ males,

At each generation we uniformly sample $n$ males (with repetitions) to be the fathers of the next male generation.

After how many generations will the population converge to only one haplo-group ?

Comment: Nobody can answer this question, it is way too general. Do you have a context? If you were to model the number of male sons of an individual by a Galton-Watson process, your question boils down to "what's the probability to have exactly one tree that survives". Is it what you are thinking?

Comment: Assume that there are $n$ sons in each generation, and you are choosing a father for each son from the previous generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Wright-Fisher model. You can find the expected time for one type to take over the population on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_drift#Time_to_fixation_or_loss), or, if you want something more official, Ewens' *Mathematical population genetics*, eqn. (3.11). It's $E[T]=-2n^2(1-1/n)\log(1-1/n)$, which is $E[T]\approx 2n$ for $n\gg 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Not the complete answer but something to help you get started.

Let's write the probability to go from $k$ different haplo-types to $l<k$ haplo-types in one step, when there are $n$ initial haplo-types.
We get the probability 
(the reasoning can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412111/m-balls-into-n-urns)):
$$\Pr[k\to l;n] = \frac{n!S_{n,l}}{(k-l)!\times k^n}$$
with $S_{n,l}$ denoting the Stirling number of the second kind.

To get the probability expected number of surviving haplo-types at  the beginning of the second step, you can use the formula $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i \times Pr[n \to i;n]$.

Using these probabilities you can describe your problem as a Markov Chain, from which you can estimate the expected time it takes to eliminate all but one haplo-type.

Comment: The expected number of haplo-types at the second generation is $$n(1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^n)$$, how can this can be seen from the formula you suggested ?

Comment: @UriGoren Please disregard the abomination I had written before. Now this is correct, but still a long way from the answer. At the same time, you could give it better tags/description, as you just have an urn problem, and nothing to do with biology.